# How to get the sum for each row?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, row, checksum

I want to find and display the row number that has the maximum sum and display the row values and this is sample input/output:
[image]

The problem is every time the maximum sum is the third row how to solve these issues.

```
   int [][] scores = new int[4][3];

    for (int i=0; i<scores.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter values for row "+i+": ");
        for (int j=0; j<scores[i].length;j++)
            scores[i][j] = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    
    int sum, sumMax, ii=0;
    for (int i=0; i<scores.length; i++)
    {
        sum =0; sumMax = 0; ii=0;
        for (int j=0; j<scores[i].length;j++)
        {
            sum += scores[i][j];
            if (sum>sumMax)
            {
                sumMax = sum;
                ii = i;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Row "+ii+" has the maximum sum");
    System.out.print("Row "+ii+" has the following values: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           System.out.print(scores[ii][j] + " ");
```

Comment: Is there a problem ? What issue do you face ?

Comment: What is the value of maximum sum?

Comment: the problem is the code apply only in row number 3 and there problem in print the values for the row that has the maximum sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print a specific row, you need one loop only

```
System.out.print("Row " + ii + " has the following values: ");
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    System.out.print(scores[ii][j] + " ");
```

Or with `Arrays.toString`

```
System.out.println("Row " + ii + " has the following values: " + Arrays.toString(scores[ii]));
```

---

Also your finding max code is **wrong**, as you reset `ii` and `sumMax` to 0 for each row, the max can only be the last line, you need to keep track of these 2 along the rows. Also use the `if` only after computing the row's sum, no need to test at every bow of every row

```
int sum, sumMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE, ii = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++) {
        sum += scores[i][j];
    }

    if (sum > sumMax) {
        sumMax = sum;
        ii = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rows while getting the input from scanner and store them in an array. Then you can search for the max value in the sums array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] scores = new int[4][3];
        int[] rowSums  = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter values for row " + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++){
                scores[i][j] = kbd.nextInt();
                rowSums[i] += scores[i][j];
            }
        }

        int index  = 0;
        int maxSum = rowSums[index];

        for(int i = 1; i < rowSums.length; i++){
            if(rowSums[i] > maxSum){
                maxSum = rowSums[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Row "+index+" has the maximum sum");
        System.out.print("Row "+index+" has the following values: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < scores[index].length; i++){
             System.out.print(scores[index][i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```